# Using sum() sql with php ActiveRecord

Tags: php, phpactiverecord

I'm using [ActiveRecord](http://phpactiverecord.org/) in my app. I need to add many objects by attribute. Currently I do it as follows:

```
foreach($objects as $object):
    $result += $object->value;
endforeach;
```

But it is very slow. I think I could get the same result but more efficient by sql sum(), so de question is can ActiveRecord return me the sum() result?

Answer (score 3):

The only aggregating function already implemented in the model is `count()`. For `sum()`, you'd have to use an SQL query. You can do that using different classes (`Connection`, `Table` or `Model`).

Here's using `find_by_sql()` of the `Model` (returns an array of models):

```
$result = FooModel::find_by_sql('SELECT SUM(`value`) AS sum FROM `foo_table`')[0]->sum;
```

Answer (score 0):

Add custom model to your lib/Model.php file

```
public static function sum($args) {
    $args = func_get_args();
    $options = static::extract_and_validate_options($args);
    $options['select'] = 'SUM('.$args[0]["sum"].')';
    if (!empty($args) && !is_null($args[0]) && !empty($args[0]))
    {
        if (is_hash($args[0]))
            $options['conditions'] = (isset($args[0]["conditions"]) ? $args[0]["conditions"] : array());
        else
            $options['conditions'] = call_user_func_array('static::pk_conditions',$args);
    }
    $table = static::table();
    $sql = $table->options_to_sql($options);
    $values = $sql->get_where_values();
    return static::connection()->query_and_fetch_one($sql->to_s(),$values); 
}
```

Then call it:

YourModel::sum(array('conditions' => 'userid = 3', 'sum' => 'your_column'));

or

YourModel::sum(array('sum' => 'your_column'));